# add a lazy child in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data

Want to add a child object without fetching it but getting LazyInitializationException.
My child is hug list so dont want to fetch all child just to add one child object.

```
@Entity
public class JobRunId{
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "jobRun", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<JobStep> jobSteps = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addStep(JobStep jobStep) {
        if (jobStep != null) {
            jobStep.setJobRun(this); 
            this.jobSteps.add(jobStep);// here getting LazyInitializationException
        }
    }
}

service class

jobRun = repository.findById(id);
//Dont want to do hibernate.initialize here as want to avoid fetch all 
 child records
JobStep jobStep = new JobStep();
//some jobStep status
jobRun.addStep(jobStep);//adding one step here to jobRun.getting error
```

is there a way just to add one child record without fetching all the child records.

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way just to add one child record without fetching all the child records.

Considering you want to add `JobStep` entities of given `JobRunId`, you can use `JOIN FETCH` directive like query. The `JOIN FETCH` directive instructs Hibernate to issue an `INNER JOIN` so JobRunId fetched along with its JobStep. The createQuery will look something similar:

```sql
    SELECT js
    FROM JobStep js
    JOIN fetch js.jobRunId 
    WHERE js.id = :jobId"
```

Alternative approach is to use DTO projection, if you do not want to modify an entity then use DTO projection. Basically, it allows you to fetch fewer columns.

I am not sure the exact details of the relation and why you managing this way. Here is good article to read [Best way to handle LazyInitializationException](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-handle-the-lazyinitializationexception/). Hope this would give you insight to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response.but join fetch will also fetch all my child object which actually I don't want as my child is more than 1000 records and just to add one record , don't want to fetch all the records.can you please let me know how dto projection works

Comment: @Rohit Given the fact you have `one-to-many` relationship but you also have filter in the form of `where` clause. I updated the answer with an article to read.

Answer (score 0):

Persist your jobStep directly (i.e. using something like `em.persist(jobStep)` or `JobStepRepository.save(jobStep)` ...

NOTE: the jobStep instance should have a reference to the JobRunId already persisted ...